# jQuery ScrollTo active button

Tags: jquery, web, scrollto

my site http://www.iancockram.com is a one page portfolio. The problem I am trying to solve is that I would like to have the menu button that is active to be highlighted.

I have tried to configure it, but can never have it working..

```
    **JQUERY**
    //scrollTo
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav ul li a').click(function(){
    var el = $(this).attr('href');
    var elWrapped = $(el);
    scrollToDiv(elWrapped, 86);
    return false;
    });

    function scrollToDiv(element,navheight){
    var offset = element.offset();
    var offsetTop = offset.top;
    var totalScroll = offsetTop-navheight;
    $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: totalScroll
    }, 500);
    }
    });//scrollTo end


    **HTML**
    <nav>
    <ul id="top-menu">
      <div id="logo"><img src="furniture/logo.png" width="242" height="90" alt="iancockram.com" title="iancockram.com"></div>
      <li class="button"> <span class="menutext"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></span></li>
      <li class="button"> <span class="menutext"><a href="#extra">Extra</a></span></li>
      <li class="button"> <span class="menutext"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></span></li>
      <li class="button"> <span class="menutext"><a href="#about">About</a></span></li>
    </ul>
```

}

Comment: What actually happens and what did you expect to happen? Can you show some screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Css class to click
Like this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav ul li a').click(function(){
    $('nav ul li a').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add some css class on onclick event of link

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add same style to clicked element, that you use for :hover.

If you want to highligh menu items also on scroll you need to set-up $(window).scroll() event, to check if height is between top and bottom of one of the divs and to applie same style as described before.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the onclick event working!!!

And now building on the idea of the having the menu items highlighted with the window.scroll function.

I have managed to have an alert show when I pass a div. But how would I code it when passing multiple divs to affect the style?

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var aPortfolio = $('.portfoliowrapper').height();
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=aPortfolio){
        alert('portfolio just passed.');
    }
  });
});
```